# Group by with min

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe and I get the following:

```
   index1  index2   results
0       0       0  8.605016
1       0       1  8.600410
2       0       2  8.585075
3       1       0  8.550355
4       1       1  8.557221
5       1       2  8.557640
6       2       0  4.360486
7       2       1  4.362304
8       2       2  4.354539`
```

I want to group by `index1` and get the value minimum. I expect an output like this:

```
   index1  index2   results
0       0       2  8.585075
1       1       0  8.550355
2       2       2  4.354539
```

Comment: Your desired output and problem description conflict, grouping on both indices would produce a df with 9 rows but you're showing 3 rows which indicates you want to group just on index1

Comment: I correct question by desired output - delete `index2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution works, if `groupby` only but `index1` - then you get desired output.

You need first `indexes` of values with `min` values by [`idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) and then select by [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html):

```
print (df.groupby('index1')['results'].idxmin())

print (df.ix[df.groupby('index1')['results'].idxmin()])
   index1  index2   results
2       0       2  8.585075
3       1       0  8.550355
8       2       2  4.354539
```

Another solution is [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregating [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
print (df.sort_values(by="results").groupby('index1', as_index=False).first())
   index1  index2   results
0       0       2  8.585075
1       1       0  8.550355
2       2       2  4.354539
```